# sub array of longest positive integer. Compiler doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript

I'm checking every number of an array, where if the number is positive and greater than 0, a variable call 'length' will be incremented. and if not then 'length' variable will be set to 0.
but for the array element 2 and 7 it's always entering else mode and setting my 'length' variable to 0. 
but clearly 2 and 7 is greater than 0.

I've already tried 3 different compiler and also chrome developer console. I can't understand what's wrong.

```js
function longestSequence(arr) {
    let longest = 0;
    let length = 0;
    for(let i of arr) {
        if(arr[i] > 0) {
            length = length + 1;
            console.log("for "+i+" length "+length);   
        }
        else {
            length = 0;
            console.log("for "+i+" length "+length);
        }
        if(length > longest) {
            longest = length;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
const ara = [3, 2, -4, 7, 1, 5, 6];
console.log(longestSequence(ara));
```

Output:

```
'for 3 length 1'
'for 2 length 0'
'for -4 length 0'
'for 7 length 0'
'for 1 length 1'
'for 5 length 2'
'for 6 length 3'
3
```

but clearly 'for 2 length 0' should be 'for 2 length 2' and 'for 7 length 0' should be 'for 7 length 1'
and the value of that function should be 4.
can anyone tell me what's wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: You're using `for-of`, but `arr[i]` should be used with `for-in`.

Comment: `for..of` works differently that `for..in` - it gives the value, not the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `i` is not the index but the array element itself, `for..of` loop iterates through each element of the iterable:

```js
function longestSequence(arr) {
    let longest = 0;
    let length = 0;
    for(let i of arr) {
        if(i > 0) {
            length = length + 1;
            console.log("for "+i+" length "+length);   
        }
        else {
            length = 0;
            console.log("for "+i+" length "+length);
        }
        if(length > longest) {
            longest = length;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
const ara = [3, 2, -4, 7, 1, 5, 6];
console.log(longestSequence(ara));
```

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Syntax):

> for (variable of iterable) {   statement }
>
> variable
>   On each iteration a value of a different property is
>   assigned to variable.    variable may be declared with const, let, or
>   var.

Comment: @h_houtarou glad to help, please hit the accept button if you found my answer helpful!